# Persistent live install, stop auto login SDDM

Tags: live-usb, persistence, auto-login, sddm

I have searched all over and have found similar posts, but they are older and for different flavors. I am not interested in doing a full install. This saves a lot of space off a full install. I also just want to see if it is possible.

I have a persistent live install using a casper-rw partition of Kubuntu 16.04. It is running very well, but I would like to disable the live user from logging in automatically. I made a new user account but no matter what settings I set (disable auto login, change auto login) it starts up and just appears to bypass the desktop manager and logs right in to the live user. I have done a lot of searching and have not found a way around this. There is no sddm folder and editing sddm.conf and removing all of the auto login entries does not help. Trying other login managers does not seem to help either. I tried Lightdm and it just goes blank, slim loads but I cannot login to my account with it. I had similar issues with 15.10 as well... Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: If it helps I think sddm is using systemd for the auto login...

Comment: I have exactly the same. I found that /etc/sddm.conf is rewritten with original values at boot time. But I don't know how.

Answer (score 0):

I found an hacky solution:

Edit the file `/etc/systemd/system/display-manager.service`

In section `[Service]` in key `ExecStartPre`, add

rm -f /etc/sddm.conf;

Just before the `[`.

Answer (score 0):

This unable-to-disable-autologin is "working as designed" for Live Persistent.

Reference: [Persistent Live USB vs. Full Linux install on a USB drive (October 2021)](https://www.fosslinux.com/49280/persistent-live-usb-vs-full-linux-install-usb-drive.htm)  which has this vital point:

> ...you should be aware that there is no login process in the
> persistent Live USB. This means that the default user has admin rights
> and does not need a sudo password to exercise their rights. Hence, a
> malicious user can boot into a persistent Live USB of another user and
> easily access the stored data, including documents, personal stuff,
> and uninstall or reconfigure applications. So, generally, Live USB
> threatens a user’s data safety.

I can confirm that Lubuntu 20.04 keeps appending the default autologin user information to the `/etc/sddm.conf` file, and that additional duplicate section takes precedence over anything you might try to edit.

I also tried the hack above and that led to a very dead end.  The system does attempt to prompt to choose the user to login with, but, there is no way to enter the password even if you know it.